# How can I change the background color of a column based on the value of another column

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, django-templates

I'm using Django framework. I have a table that contains some columns. I need to change the background of the aht column based on the agent_target column so if the value lower than or equal the target the background should be green, else it should be red.

```html
                {% for item in data %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.loginid }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.agentname }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.team }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.queue_name }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.sumduration}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.countduration}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle aht">{{ item.aht}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle target">{{ item.agent_target}}</td>

                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

When I try to access the value of the AHT column using the below js it returns undefined value

```
console.log(document.getElementById("aht").value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Non javascript**

You can actually do this without javascript

in your css

```
.over_target{
   background-color:"red" /* or use #ff0000 style */
}

.on_target {
   background-color: "green"
}
```

then replace your current td aht line with

```
<td class="text-center align-middle 
   {% if item.aht > item.agent_target %}
       over_target
   {% else %}
       under_target
   {% endif %}
   ">{{ item.aht}}</td>
```

**javascript**

If you really want to use javascript, it gets a bit more complicated.

You have added 'aht' as a class.  You want to uniquely identify *each* cell, so you will need an id instead.  To use 'aht' as an ID you would use;

```
<td class="text-center align-middle" id="aht">{{ item.aht}}</td>
```

However, you're using a forloop to loop through a list, each of which you will want to have a unique id, because otherwise other rows will have a cell with the same id. To get around that we can grab a number from the django {{forloop.counter}}

```
<td class="text-center align-middle" id="aht{{forloop.counter}}">{{ item.aht}}</td>
```

Use the same format for the target column

Then, to set the colour for the target column you can use something like this (after the table code):

```
<script>
function getColour(aht, target) {
     if (aht > target) {
        return "red"}
     return "green"
}


 {% for item in data %}
    aht = document.getElementById('aht{{forloop.counter}}).innerText
    target= document.getElementById('target{{forloop.counter}}).innerText
    targetColour = getColour(aht, target)
    document.getElementById('aht{{forloop.counter}}').style.backgroundColor = targetColour

 {%endfor%}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is trying to find a tag with id equal to "aht", not class "aht".
*value* is not a property to find text for table value, because this is a *td* element, not *input* element, you have to use innerText property.  You can try *innerText* or *textContent*

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.aht').innerText)
```

Please bear in mind this is only trying to get the text value of the first *td* element.

What you are trying to do can be accomplished by ternary operator in Django template. This is like an if, but shorter.

```
<style>
.bg-green {
background-color: green;
}
.bg-red {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
{% for item in data %}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.loginid }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.agentname }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.team }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.queue_name }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.sumduration}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.countduration}}</td>
                        <td class='text-center align-middle aht {{ item.aht <= item.agent_target |yesno:"bg-green,bg-red,bg-none" }}' 
>{{ item.aht}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle target">{{ item.agent_target}}</td>
    
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Please try the code and let me know if it worked!
*If you think my solution answered your question please Accept this answer, thanks very much! *

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno